# How do I identify and fix a buzzing noise in my commercial freezer?

Tags: refrigerator, noise-reduction

I have been using a [second-hand TRUE commercial freezer](https://ancasterfoodequipment.com/true-commercial-freezers/) for almost 13 years for my home catering business. It has been making a buzzing noise since yesterday.

How can I identify the source of the problem?

Comment: `How can I identify the source of the problem?` ... you can use your ears to figure out where the buzzing originates

Comment: Could be the *I'm getting too warm* alarm, which is frequently a buzzer.

Comment: DIY repair tips will depend, entirely, on what the source of the problem is, and will be an excellent 2nd question. As @jsotola suggested, listening carefully may allow you to identify where the issue is. You may also be able to feel it, or, putting your fingers on different places (be careful, the coils can be _hot_!) might be enough to damp the vibration and stop the noise which will also tell you where it's vibrating. Look for broken parts.

Comment: Has the freezer vents / fan etc been cleaned or are they covered or clogged with dust?

Comment: @Freeman your comment is what my answer would have been; maybe it should *be* an answer,,,

Comment: There is not enough information to guess at the problem, where the buzz is coming from on the unit would be a good start , is the fridge still cooling?  Is the unit lighted are the lights working?  VTC.

Answer (score 1):

DIY repair tips will depend, entirely, on what the source of the problem is, and will be an excellent 2nd question. This answer will provide suggestions for *finding* the buzz, since we can't help you fix it until we know what the problem is.

Here are some tips for finding the source of the buzzing noise:

- As [jsotola suggested in a comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/198729/how-do-i-identify-and-fix-a-buzzing-noise-in-my-commercial-freezer?noredirect=1#comment357727_198729), listening carefully may allow you to identify where the issue is.

  - You may have to put your ear very close to different parts of the freezer.
  - You may have to stick your head *inside* to see if you can identify where it's coming from.
  - It's possible that something was put in the freezer with a stiff but flexible piece sticking out, and that protrusion was pushed against the inside wall of freezer just hard enough to buzz from the general vibrations of the freezer running.
- You may also be able to feel excessive vibration by putting your fingers on different parts of the freezer.

  - Be careful, the coils can be hot!
  - Touching different parts might be enough to damp the vibration and stop the noise which will also tell you where it's vibrating.
- Look for broken parts.

  - If a piece of plastic has recently broken (due to age, most likely) the broken parts may be vibrating against each other when the compressor is running.

I'm sure there are other things you can do to locate the source of the buzzing - use some creativity and imagination if these suggestions don't help you pinpoint the issue.

Once you've identified the problem, if you're not able to figure out a solution on your own (move that box inside the freezer, if that's the problem, etc.) post a new question, with a complete description of where the buzzing is coming from (pictures always help!) and I'm sure you'll get good recommendations on how to fix it.